# Perl: system command returns before it is done

Tags: perl

I'm using a a few `system()` commands in my perl script that is running on Linux.

The commands I run with the `system()` function output their data to a log which I then parse to decide what to do next.
I noticed that sometimes it looks like the code that parses the log file (which comes **after** the `system()` function) doesn't use the **final** log.

For example, I search for a "test pass" phrase in the log file - and the script doesn't find it even though when I open the log it is there.

Another example - I try to delete the folder where the log was placed but it doesn't let me because it's "Not empty". When I try to delete it manually it is deleted with errors.

(These examples happen every now and then, but most of the time they don't)

It looks like some kind of "timing" problem to me. How can I solve it?

Comment: _Timing_, you mean buffering?

Comment: How do you "delete manually with errors"? In fact, you should show the code that produces the behaviour you describe. Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Sounds like the output by the command is not yet properly written when your script tries to go on. Most likely it is still in one of the many buffers it has to passs through on its way to the harddisk. You could probably solve that by sleeping some millieseconds or, if you want to brute force it on a Linux system, insert `system sync` after your first `system` to flush the filesystem.

Comment: @DeVadder what you said sounds exactly like the problem, and most likely - the solution. Should I use it only once?

Comment: What types of commands are used to generate the log? Maybe the log generator forks, and the process that you call with `system()` terminates before all of its children have terminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be safe and are on Linux, call `system sync;` after every command that writes to the disk before reading from the disk. That will force the OS to write everything still buffered to the filesystem and only return afterwards. Thus you can be sure that when it is finished, everything you wrote to files now actually has arrived there.

But be aware, that may be overkill in many situations. There are reasons for those buffers and manually calling `sync` constantly is most likely not the fastest way of achieving things. See also http://linux.die.net/man/8/sync

If, for example, you have something else that you could do between the writing and the reading, like some calculations or whatever, that would likely be enough and you would not waste time by telling the OS that you know better how and when it has to do it's jobs. ^^

But if perfect efficiency is not your main concern (and you should not be using Perl if it was), `system sync;` after everything that modifies files and before accessing those files is probably okay and safe.

Comment: I still face this issue. It happens much less, but still happens every now and then. Is there a way for me to make sure that all buffers complete writing before I continue the script?

Comment: Hmm, i am not sure why that happens. Either it could be something like Stefan Majewsky suggested in the comment or maybe it has something to do with what the actual disk does to write the files. Hard disks do have their own buffers, but they should be transparent for you, i believe. Either way, if you do not want to dive deep, i would suggest to just sleep for a second after the writing, if that is possible for you. If the problem persists, then it most likely is not due to slow writing to disk as that should never be that slow but probably has something to do how the logs are generated.